# GET request to website from java returns 403 even after including User-Agent property

Tags: java, get

So I am trying to gather content of a website (https://search.torrents.io/) from a java application using a GET request.

Given the correct torrent infohash after the https://search.torrents.io/ like for example: 
 https://search.torrents.io/1A1B3A4C80431A536A160FD94C2C13AFD38AF108 will give me some info on the torrent with the corresponding infohash(just for context, not important for the issue).

When sending the GET request from a browser or postman the website gives back response 200, but querying the website from a java application doesn't seem to work and I get error 403-forbidden:

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://search.torrents.io/1A1B3A4C80431A536A160FD94C2C13AFD38AF108
```

Here is how I do it:

```
try {
        rss = new URL("https://search.torrents.io/" + infohash);

        httpconn = (HttpsURLConnection)rss.openConnection();

        httpconn.setRequestMethod  ("GET");
        httpconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        httpconn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",       "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36");

        httpconn.setRequestProperty("Host",     "search.torrents.io:443");
        httpconn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
        httpconn.setRequestProperty("Sec-Fetch-Dest",       "document");

        httpconn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpconn.setDoInput(true);
        httpconn.setDoOutput(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return(TT.ERROR);
    }

    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rss.openStream()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return(TT.ERROR);
    }
```

Now at the start I didn't add any request properties to the requests - got the 403 error and found out I had to include the User-agent property for it to behave like a browser request, but that didn't work either.

Then I read more into it and someone proposed I check out the live http headers plugin for chrome and I basically added all the properties that were preset and seemed to make sense for the request.

What I also found out is that adding user agent works for a lot of other websites but not for this one. Also seems weird, that it works from postman, which is not really a browser either. Shouldn't the requests be the equal to the server if they contain the same headers?

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this?
Any input is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Matic

Comment: Try using the Network tab in Chrome's developer tools to get the exact fields and data of the request. Then put it all into your java code and run it. More info here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network

Comment: Do you know if I put all the fields of the request in java connection should the server see no difference between the browser and the java call?

Comment: If you copy it all down, unless you missed something, the server should see it exactly as just another web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions.

So, I didn't fix the issue, the problem is probably the website I'm querying is recognizing the queries are coming from the default java library. I fixed it by just using another library.